# How are monsters/creatures/npcs presented in Fate setting manuals?

Tags: monsters, fate, fate-core, publishing, adventure-writing

**Background**

I'd like to add a list of creatures, monsters, and characters to a Fate project, like the D&D Monster Manual. I understand that the GM usually writes NPCs custom per game, but I want to present some sort of list of statistics/values/aspects. This is for two main reasons:

1. *Worldbuilding:* There are a lot of different sorts of non-human (and not-even-*remotely*-human) creatures in the setting, and they're all fair game as far as conflict is concerned.
2. *Workload:* If I can, I'd like to make less work for the GM, why force them to make up stats for creatures that I'm already presenting information for?

**In what format are creatures/NPCs normally presented?**

A single stat block for each? One for Nameless, Supporting, and Main NPC levels? Or are they just described however makes sense, leaving the balancing to the GM?

I'd prefer actual example stat blocks from actual bestiaries/NPC lists.

Answer (score 3):

Some short example stat blocks exist in the Adventure Creation section of the War of Ashes part of the [Fate SRD](https://fate-srd.com/war-ashes/adventure-creation-expanded).  As with most other examples, they're minimal.  EG:

> Vidaar Sailor
>
> Weight: 1 (Sentian-sized)
>
> Vidaar Sailor; We Are Skyhammers!
>
> Skilled (+2) at: Sailing, fighting with boarding axes, climbing in the
>   rigging.
>
> Bad (-2) at: Planning, social situations.
>
> Stress
>
> o
>
> Astute gamers will have noticed that using "skilled at" and "bad at"
>   are roughly the equivalent of giving minions a few stunts and flaws.

There is also the [Fate Bestiary](http://fatesf.blogspot.com/p/fate-bestiary.html), [Fate Pathfinder Bestiary](http://www.killershrike.com/Fate/Fae/Pathfinder/Content/Characters/Bestiary.aspx), and the [Fate Creature Decks](http://inkwellideas.com/fate_creatures/) which are basically Wiki format with a lot of example critters.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure it's 100% what you're looking for, but [Creating The Opposition](https://fate-srd.com/fate-core/creating-and-playing-opposition) in the FATE srd may be helpful as it has sample stat blocks for NPCs and enemies.

There is also a book out called The [FATE Adversary Toolkit](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/219203/Fate-Adversary-Toolkit) that has several stat block examples and is pay what you want.

The general rule of thumb is to just make trimmed down sheets for your npcs or generic monsters with just 1-3 aspects and 3 shift stress track. An NPC is treated no differently than a 'monster', just like how 5e has NPC stat blocks for generic NPC enemies like Guards.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at the [Dresden Files RPG: Our World](http://www.evilhat.com/home/dresden-files-rpg-our-world/) book.  Although there are a number of difference between DF flavored Fate and Core Fate, it will still give you a very good idea of how to present both generic and specific NPCs.

However, to answer the specific question, you should probably include stat blocks, with two or three difficulty variants, as well as a general, textual description and ecology of each creature.

Comment: Before I go out and buy just the Our World book, do you have an example offhand?

Comment: I can't find one online, but I hardly did an exhaustive search.  You may or may not be able to find one.  Or maybe check out a friend's copy or one at a local book store.